# How to use a variable for object's owner (schema)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In Oracle we can use a variable instead of the object's owner. The value of this variable will be prompted by Oracle when the scripts starts.

Something like `CREATE TABLE **&owner.**MY_TABLE.`

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with SQL Server but I failed to find how to do it.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Starting with 2005, those are known as schemas.

Comment: It's version 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern versions of SQL Server, this is actually the *schema*, not the owner. You can't parameterize this and must concatenate a command:

```
DECLARE @schema sysname = N'owner';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + N'.my_table(cols...);';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

If this is being specified by an end user, you may want to validate that it is a proper schema first, e.g.:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = @schema)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Invalid schema %s!', 11, 1, @schema);
  RETURN;
END
```

A really lazy way is to set the callers default schema to the target, and then don't specify the schema name. [This is a bad idea](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) but I'm mentioning it for completeness.